# Polynomino combinatorial placing game.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I think everyone knows the combinatorial games that are of the form:

*Anne and Bob are playing a game on an $m \times n$ board. They alternatively chose a piece made out of $x$ $1 \times 1$ squares joined edge to edge. The loser is the one that cannot place a piece on the board. Knowing that Anne begins, does she have a winning strategy?*

I was courious if there exists a general result for choices of $m,n,x$.

I searched the internet and found that when $x=2$ the game is called *Cram*, the strategy for even-even and even-odd boards being trivially known, while for odd-odd boards only in specific cases with smaller values of $m,n$, where the *Sprague–Grundy* value can be calculated.

I'm not sure if there are other generalizations of this :(.

Comment: Please show that you have made a little "state of the art" ; for example, googling with "placement strategy rectangles board", one gets answers like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1487970/305862) on this site.

Comment: some more links maybe ? Im not into combinatorical games

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game) I guess. But uncertain what your pieces are ?

Comment: Are your pieces all the same and x times 1 ?

Comment: @mick If there are any results on this case then sure.