# Cram game with pieces of length 3.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I think everyone knows the game of Cram [(see my post from yesterday)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805894/polynomino-combinatorial-placing-game)
I tried to find for what boards the first player has a strategy when each piece is made out of 3 pieces, however I was unable to find a strategy that cover that many cases.

If $m$ and $n$ are both odd then the first player can place a "line" piece that has it's center piece in the center square of the board. After that the first player can just use the "symmetry" strategy.

If $m$ and $n$ are both even, the second player can mirror the first one.  –  [user3257842](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/365433/user3257842)

I've also studied the case with $m=1$. I didn't manage to find some sort of periodicity. I tried using the *Guy-Smith Periodicity Theorem* for Octal Games.

Any ideas or thoughts on this?

Comment: If $m$ and $n$ are both even, the second player can mirror the first one (still using symmetry), to win. The odd-even cases are the mystery.

Comment: Do pieces have to be straight, or are bent 3's (L shaped) allowed?

Comment: @paw88789 The general case would be for straight and L-shaped pieces, however, if you find a result with just straight or just L-shaped pieces that is fine too. To be clear, this is not homework, just a curiosity of mine.

Comment: The case where $m=1$ is a finite octal game, so it is conjectured to be eventually periodic.  The game is $0.007$: a legal move is to remove exactly three tokens from a heap and split the remainder into zero, one, or two heaps.  Note that this is essentially equivalent to Treblecross (1-dimensional tic-tac-toe, with only Xs): in that case, you lose if you place an X next to or one square away from another.  But that's the same constraint as placing $1 \times 3$ pieces that can't overlap.  There is literature on Treblecross; I think it's still unsolved whether/how it's periodic.